# Css selector for only the <select> element without its <option> tags IE8

Tags: html, css, firefox, internet-explorer-8, css-selectors

I would like to color (i.e. highlight as erroneous) a `select` element, but not its `option` tags. In FF I achieve this by applying a style to the `select` element and applying another style to the `option` tags. Here are the styles:

```
.highlight{
    background-color: #FB6F6E;
}

.highlight > option{
    background: #dfdfdf;
}
```

This looks as I want in FF (16.0.1),

[image]

but in IE8 (quirks mode) all options are colored:

[image]

So is there a way to achieve this in IE8?

**EDIT** I would preferably use something that does not involve giving classes to `option` tags or using javascript. I know those solutions work, but it feels sort of a hack. Maybe the DOCTYPE issue solves the problem, I just wonder if adding a DOCTYPE would alter the current design.

**EDIT** As some of you suggested, I have added a DOCTYPE (HTML 4.01 Transitional). IE8 is still in quirks mode, but the selectbox is rendered a little bit differently:

[image]

The border of the select is red, but still not the whole selectbox. Any ideas?

Comment: @Clyde Lobo: no I am not using a DOCTYPE.

Comment: Then you need to start using a DOCTYPE. It makes IE behave more predictably.

Comment: In that case, not possible. You have to force it to standards mode in order for it to work.

Comment: @Robert K: but then I would need to check all my pages to render correctly. Since everything is done to work in quirks mode. Or there is no need to check/test?

Comment: I suspect that not having a DOCTYPE is causing your IE8 into compatibility mode. Please use a DOCTYPE

Comment: Why is DOCTYPE so important? Can you explain a little bit how it works and what it does? (even just links are welcome).

Comment: It causes a browser to render a web page as closely to the standards as it can. This ensures greater consistency across different browsers. If IE is rendering something very differently from other browsers it's often a result of quirks mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I could not find a solution (that does not use javascript) for this problem.
The client accepted the selectboxes as they are.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
.highlight option, .highlight:focus option {
    background: #dfdfdf;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work. The whole selectbox becomes gray as it it were not highlighted.

Comment: @Atticus: `:focus` is not supported in quirks mode.

Answer (score 1):

Works(ish) if you apply a different class to the options, like this...

```
<html>
<body>
    <select class="highlight">
        <option>Please select...</option>
        <option class="nohighlight">One</option>
        <option class="nohighlight">Two</option>
        <option class="nohighlight">Three</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vXFZe

Comment: Thanks, I know this but I don't want to rewrite all my select boxes.. in the whole project.

Comment: You could apply the class using javascript / JQuery?

Comment: Yes that is true indeed, but that would be quite an overhead for several selectboxes on a page, each with 300 options ... executing every time the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

I spent some time experimenting and I came up with this:

```
$('.highlight').on('click', 'option', function() {

    $(this).css('background-color', 'tomato').siblings().css('background-color', 'white');

});
```

Basically you force the background color onto the selected `<option>` using javascript. The only artifact I saw was that the selected `<option>` will have the red color in the list as well. I would have preferred an all CSS solution, but this works in IE.